# Why do some spell checker mark "copiable" as an error?

Tags: orthography, suffixes

Some of my spell checkers (including the one in vim, and the build-in one in gmail) mark the form "copiable" as an error, and insist on "copyable". This doesn't seem to make sense; the rule I always learned was that "y become i if preceded by a consonant when adding a suffix, unless the suffix starts with an i: eg "copied" or "copier", but "copying". According to this rule, the correct spelling would be "copiable", which is what I always use. But I often see "copyable", which doesn't seem right to me. (For what it's worth: Merriam Webster says that the word doesn't exist, in either form, the American Heritage Dictionary gives both forms, and the Oxford English Dictionary only gives "copiable".)

What is the correct usage, and why?

Comment: Uh, what is a "rule"???

Comment: [Google 1grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=copiable%2Ccopyable&year_start=1800&corpus=26&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccopiable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccopyable%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccopiable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccopyable%3B%2Cc0) seem to suggest that apart from brief reversals around 1850 and 1950, _copyable_ has been the favoured (_not_ the only correct) variant. As AHD licenses both, it's best to consider both acceptable. Choose one (perhaps the more commonly used one?) and stick with it.

Comment: [The corresponding results from the British corpus Google uses](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=copiable%2Ccopyable&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) show far greater variation; _copiable_ was in favour from 1990 to 2010, but has been pushed firmly into second place since then.

Answer (score 3):

The 'rule' you've learnt doesn't apply to all words. There are more "exceptions to rules" than there are "rules". For example, you can't write *plaiable* instead of *playable*.

Some other exceptions are *buyable*, *repayable*, *displayable*, *employable*, *enjoyable* etc.

In case of *copyable/copiable*, they're both used, I don't know why.

According to [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=copiable%2Ccopyable&year_start=1800&corpus=26&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccopiable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccopyable%3B%2Cc0), *copyable* is much more prevalent:
[image: Google Ngram results for copyable/copiable]

Both are correct and acceptable. Use whichever you want but be consistent.

Comment: Your examples all conform to the rule. The rule say when "y is preceded by a consonant". When it is preceded by a vowel, as in all of your examples, it doesn't change.

Comment: @JamesKanze, Not sure what you mean. But compare *rely-reliable* with *play-playable*. The "rule" you're talking about is inconsistent.

Comment: rely-reliable might be an exception, although there may also be something additional with regards to where the accent falls. I can't think of any exceptions where the -y is unaccented and preceded by a consonant.

Comment: @James: What are you trying to say? Can you please explain with examples?

Comment: @JamesKanze The problem that I, and apparently others here, are having is that your use of "rule". This implies an invariable result. Unfortunately, English is quite an irregular language as it has multiple origins. I will offer you *“There are no rules in English, only guidance. Some guidance looks like a rule; it probably isn't."*

Comment: @Greybeard So basically, it is an exception. The rule is one I learned in school many years ago. Along with a lot of others: for example, to make the plural of a word ending in y preceded by a consonant, change the y to i and add es. To date, I've never seen any exceptions to that. The issue here was that it seemed to be a unique exception to a more general rule about adding an ending to a word ending in y preceded by a consonant. A rule which copy follows, in most other case: copier, copied, etc.

Comment: @JamesKanze I take your point about "y/ies": there appear on the face of it to be no exceptions currently, but **currently** is the operative word. There is no authority that addresses matters of language. There is a "deep fat fryer" but the man who fries the fish is the "frier" - I have seen the former used for the latter, but not the latter for the former.

Comment: @Greybeard [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rule) includes the broader sense with the definition '**rule** 2a(1): a usually valid generalization', licensing this usage. Doesn't OED?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah! and there we have it - the utter uselessness of the word "rule": it is rather like having a number that means "four" yet ocassionally means anything from 2 to 6. The "rule" at 2a(1) in MW (Mostly Wrong) is, in fact, "a ***general*** rule". Students of English do not grasp this meaning of "rule", and go about talking of "rules" and exceptions. The word "rule" is a great hindrance to the leaching and learning of English. English is a living language - I could wax lyrical... *“There are no rules in English, only guidance. Some guidance looks like a rule; it probably isn't."*

Comment: @Greybeard So you prefer not to quote OED here, as it's not what you'd want.